# How to create regex to not to accept only special character or number

Tags: javascript, regex

I how to create regex to not to accept only special character or number.
for eg:

it should throw error if string contain :

1. @$%^^@
2. 1231232

but should not throw error if string contain :

1. hi@
2. hi
3. hi@1
4. hi4
5. @hi

Comment: How about `/[a-z0-9]+.*/gi`?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @MinarMnr i tried with simple regex which accept only alpabets

Comment: You want to neumeric as well?

Comment: please post the code you tried.

Comment: `^(?![^a-zA-Z]+$)(?!$).*$`
Demo - https://regex101.com/r/TPeCmt/2

Comment: @Rajesh i tried with your given regex but it is accepting numbers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use regex which allow `alpha bates` compulsory

```
/.*[a-z]+.*/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex and let me know. It is also accept white space:

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/
```

Comment: this will also match `1231232`, while it should not